# React,Storybook - TS2307: Cannot find module 'Button' or its corresponding type declarations CAN SB RESOLVE?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have pure React project (with one Button component) created by "create-reat-app" and I use absolute paths that works with importing Button component to App.js. I've added Storybook and got error while: import { Button, ButtonProps } from 'Button';

The absolute path 'Button' throws an error TS2307 as in title of this post

Project structure:

```
- App.js
- tsconfig.json
--src
--Button
---Button.js
```

I tried to add tsconfig with no result:

````
  "compilerOptions": {
    //    remove error Cannot use JSX unless '--jsx' flag is provided
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src",
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
    ]
}```
````

Comment: what error you got ?

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`import { Button, ButtonProps } from 'Button';`

 to 
`import { Button, ButtonProps } from './Button';`